# Can't resolve crypto in web worker (Electron build only)

Tags: electron, web-worker, quasar-framework

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in ...
```

The code appeared to be happy when in the main browser thread, with or without Electron. And was happy with [worker-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin) for the normal web app build. But the combination of both an Electron build (Quasar's `quasar dev -m electron` command) *and* using worker-plugin triggered the above error.

This is Quasar 1.x, which is using WebPack 4.44.2.

(All my web searches have been coming up with Angular-specific problems, or WebPack V5 problems, neither of which apply here.)

Answer (score -1):

In one project this fixed it:

```
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
},
```

In another, practically identical project (same version of Quasar, WebPack, Electron, etc.) it made no difference.

In that other project what fixed it was changing this bit of code `require('crypto').webcrypto` into `eval("require('crypto').webcrypto")`.

I then had to append `// eslint-disable-line` to that line to stop eslint complaining.

I.e. webpack doesn't look inside `eval()` commands. It works but is a bit hacky :-(

NOTE: when doing this, the above "browser" entry in package.json is not needed.

I think the underlying problem *might* be that Quasar sets both `nodeIntegration` and `nodeIntegrationInWorker` to true, by default. When I looked at the contents of `process` just before the above `require()`, which is running inside a web worker, in a webapp it is a simple `browser:true` object, whereas in Electron it is the full Node version of that object.